# Unable to connect to postgres database through heroku

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku

I have a postgres database that I created through heroku. I am trying to access it through psql with the command:

```
cse-190-fortune matanvardi$ psql "dbname=dccemfsa6camml host=ec2-54-235-152-226.compute-1.amazonaws.com \
user=tfmfbqxqjznsbl password=********* port=5432 sslmode=require"
```

I get this error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "ec2-54-235-152-226.compute-1.amazonaws.com" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I've cloned the repository and I'm logged in, I simply cannot figure out what is wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any outbound-filtering firewall in place?

Answer (score 2):

To access your Heroku database from the command line use the command:

> heroku pg:psql

---

Edit:

I ran your command from my machine.  If course I don't have your password but I got:

```
$  psql "dbname=dccemfsa6camml host=ec2-54-235-152-226.compute-1.amazonaws.com user=tfmfbqxqjznsbl port=5432 sslmode=require"
Password:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "tfmfbqxqjznsbl"
```

Which means I was able to connect, which is farther than you got.  It must be a problem with your network setup.

Comment: that gives me the same result as i mentioned above

Comment: @MatanVardi Then you have a problem with your network, probably a too-strict firewall or a misconfigured router somewhere.